# Stacked bar chart in matplotlib – how to code with lots and lots of categories?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart in matplotlib, but I have a large number of categories in each bar (around 120). How would I go about coding this in an automated fashion, without having to define each category manually? Solutions I've seen online opt for the manual version, as seen in the code pasted below (see link for original source): https://www.weirdgeek.com/2018/11/plotting-stacked-bar-graph/

The bronzes, silvers, and golds variables are what I mean when I say defining categories manually. This is something I'd like to avoid.

```
countries = ['Norway', 'Germany', 'Canada', 'United States', 'Netherlands']
bronzes = np.array([10,7,10,6,6])
silvers = np.array([14,10,8,8,6])
golds = np.array([14,14,11,9,8])
ind = [country for country in countries]

plt.bar(ind, golds, width=0.6, label='golds', color='gold', bottom=silvers+bronzes)
plt.bar(ind, silvers, width=0.6, label='silvers', color='silver', bottom=bronzes)
plt.bar(ind, bronzes, width=0.6, label='bronzes', color='#CD7F32')

plt.xticks(ind, countries)
plt.ylabel("Medals")
plt.xlabel("Countries")
plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.title("2018 Winter Olympics Top Scorers")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Are you opposed to using pandas?

Comment: no actually I'm using pandas for the data. so definitely open to solutions with pandas

Answer (score 0):

An often used tactic is to use a numpy variable for the bottom. It gets initialized with zero and incremented via [numpy magic](https://realpython.com/numpy-array-programming/).

Writing everything as a `for` loop has the benefit that the common parameters only need to be written once, and only need to be changed in one place. (In this example there is only the common width, but also edgecolor, fill style, transparency etc. could be set.)

```
bottom = 0
for medal, label, color in zip ([bronzes, silvers, golds],
                                ['bronzes', 'silvers', 'golds'],
                                ['#CD7F32', 'silver', 'gold']):
    plt.bar(ind, medal, width=0.6, label=label, color=color, bottom=bottom)
    bottom += medal
```

Without a loop, this example would be as follows.  When there would be many  more categories it would be harder to maintain.

```py
bottom = 0
plt.bar(ind, bronzes, width=0.6, label='bronzes', color='#CD7F32')
bottom += bronzes
plt.bar(ind, silvers, width=0.6, label='silvers', color='silver', bottom=bottom)
bottom += silvers
plt.bar(ind, golds, width=0.6, label='golds', color='gold', bottom=bottom)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this using pandas plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

countries = ['Norway', 'Germany', 'Canada', 'United States', 'Netherlands']
bronzes = np.array([10,7,10,6,6])
silvers = np.array([14,10,8,8,6])
golds = np.array([14,14,11,9,8])

df = pd.DataFrame({'golds':golds, 'silvers':silvers, 'bronzes':bronzes}, index = countries)

df.plot.bar(stacked=True, color=['gold','silver', '#CD7F32'], title='2018 Winter Olympics Top Scorers')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks – but I see the individual categories are still being defined manually here, e.g.: bronzes = np.array([10,7,10,6,6]). I have 120 of these. do I need to define them each manually?

Comment: You can concat the into one dataframe and plot the entire dataframe each category as a column in the dataframe.

Comment: You will need to somehow match the columns to the exact column name you want to plot.

Comment: How are you getting the np.arrays themselves?

Comment: they are values in a pandas groupby/count variable: a = severity1.groupby('Weather_Condition')['Severity'].count()

Comment: so i was going to get each of those values into a list or numpy array

Comment: `pd.concat([severity1.groupby(i)['Severity'].count() for i in List_of_Weather_Conditions], axis=1)`  I think this will build a dataframe you want.